# Dependency Walker of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in my C Sharp Project 
When I run my exe on the target machine it crashes.
I used a software called Dependency Walker which would tell me if there is a dependency not getting satisfied. According to this it needs MSISH.dll which is an Internet Explorer DLL located under the Program Files Folder
I don't understand this dependency

Comment: Please rephrase and rearrange your question. I find it hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the versions of Entity Framework depends in any way on MSISH.dll. EF is written entirely in managed code and does not directly depend on any native/COM components.

Comment: i misread the dependency walker